# File / Folder picker in Titanium Developer Studio (Desktop)?

Tags: desktop, titanium

Is there any component to select file/folder in Titanium Desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. See the documentation for Titanium.UI.UserWindow's methods [openFileChooserDialog](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/desktop/latest/Titanium.UI.UserWindow.openFileChooserDialog-method.html) and [openFolderChooserDialog](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/desktop/latest/Titanium.UI.UserWindow.openFolderChooserDialog-method.html)